# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

ExpressionEngine Answers's [1st moderator election](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Anna_MediaGirl] [image: Alex Kendrick] [image: Derek Hogue]

Please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5962301400154112/0).

Also, please join me in thanking [the Pro Tempore moderator team](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/moderator-pro-tem-announcement), who shepherded this site through the beta period!

Comment: Congrats and thanks to all!

Comment: Thanks much folks!

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

Well done all, with hearty congratulations and thanks to Anna, Alex and Derek.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats guys! I look forward to arguing the merits of a... I mean, ***agreeing*** with you guys on many issues! lol

Thanks for all your continued and future efforts!